# Is this approach 'agile'? Separating use-cases into sprints/iterations

Tags: agile, scrum, agile-project-management, agile-processes

This may be a weird question and please bear with me, I am completely new into this.

I have a list of 20 requirements (use cases) which I received from my client. With him, I prioritized this list of requirements (1 highest 3 lowest). I wrote for every requirement a use case scenario (rather than user story). I also have a use case diagram and some technical designs (class diagram, database diagram).

Now, my plan is to separate this list of 20 requirements into 5 sprints. Each sprint lasts one week.
During every meeting with my client, I can show the product with 4 new use cases implemented. If one of them isn't finished, I move it to the next sprint and my client can request a change during this meeting. During this change, the specific use case diagram and classdiagram/database diagram may be changed.

Is this considered to be Agile? (Even though he gave me the full 20 requirements from the start of the project)

Comment: This is an agile process question, not a programming question. Will be almost totally opinion based as well.

Comment: Sorry, I thought agile process questions are allowed here.

Comment: Guidelines are here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Agile is sort of a big tent, but I would not apply that label to the process you've described. You are describing lots of upfront design work and a full specs up front. The schedule assumes all the req take the same amount of time to implement, thought you acknowledge that it could slip.

The primary agile feature I see is the tight (weekly) feedback loop with client.

I recommend trying on http://pm.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks for your comment & will ask it to be sure ;)

Answer (score -2):

This is not considered as Scrum:
- Schedule is prefixed (5 sprints).
- Velocity is prefixed (4 use cases/sprint).
- No scrum ceremony is followed as such.
- All requirements are given upfront.

Please refer - https://www.scrumalliance.org/why-scrum/core-scrum-values-roles